# How to bake without an oven?

Tags: baking, cookies, charcoal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to bake a cake without an oven?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22889/is-it-possible-to-bake-a-cake-without-an-oven)

I'm a poor lady who can't afford an oven. I have pots here, charcoal, and aluminum foil. What could be tricks to use charcoal as an alternative for me to bake? I really want to try bake cookies.

Comment: First world problem? Internet but no oven?

Comment: Baking cookies is exceedingly difficult without an even heat at a steady and reliable temperature.

Comment: Back when I was a poor college student, we would bake cookies in a toaster oven.

Comment: @TFD, hahaha. Well we have an oven toaster but not an oven. Cakes and oven cooking are not my family's thing, everything's done on a gas stove.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do anything with charcoal.

One trick that we used to do when we were camping was to line a cardboard box with foil. Several metal grates or skewers would be stabbed into the box walls and a grate with a few coals hung near the bottom.

We would use it to bake bread and pizzas. To control the temperature use more or fewer coals.

[image: Cardboard oven]

As long as you are building things- another option to consider is solar oven.
They consist of an insulated container, a transparent window, and a reflector. There are a [great many models](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=solar%20oven&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1726&bih=943&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=aS5zUMfdHsLy2QXG3YH4Cg#um=1&hl=en&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=solar%20oven&oq=solar%20oven&gs_l=img.12...0.0.0.56768.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.GQogiySSV40&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=8807e830ac866bd9&biw=1726&bih=943) to choose from. Some of the more permanent models can get above 350F as long as there is direct sunlight.

This model was just one of top results from Google but it is a typical design:

[image]

Comment: Your answer AND the pictures ROCK, Sobachatina!