# How can you convert Dried Seaweed into Roasted Nori, on a Frigidaire electric cook top?

Tags: vegetables

My sister's Caucasian. We speak no Korean. We don't know the correct terminology, so I'm using pictures for clarity. He's leasing an apartment that has merely a Frigidaire 30'' Electric Cooktop like this, no oven.

[image]

He loves Roasted Nori. Every week, he visits his Korean supermarket to buy them.

[image]

[image]

One of the cashiers saw from his membership card that she buys much seaweed. His English was broken and rudimentary. As my sister heard, he vouched that making nori at home is cheaper and easier. He recommended these two different packs of Ito-Wakame Dried Seaweed, and she bought them both. But after opening the packages, sister doesn't know what to do! Help please!

[image]

[image]

Comment: very closely related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22889/is-it-possible-to-bake-a-cake-without-an-oven

Comment: Is the question about how to use this particular stove to roast, or is the the question about how to convert these ingredients + tools into roasted nori?

Comment: @rumtscho that's not really related.  Nori isn't typically roasted in an oven.

Comment: Who is "he"?  Your sister's husband?  You don't say.

Comment: @FuzzyChef thank you for correcting me. When I read "roasting", I automatically assumed that the original is prepared in an oven. I will leave the link sitting around for now, because it doesn't seem harmful, especially with your comment, but if you (or somebody else) thinks it is better gone, please cast a comment flag.

Comment: @moscafj "is the the question about how to convert these ingredients + tools into roasted nori?" This. Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, that's not the right seaweed for making nori, and second it's unlikely that your sister actually wants to make nori by hand.

Nori is [made from Porphyra yezoensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nori) and closely related seaweeds, which are not used for any other culinary purpose, and thus rarely sold in stores in forms other than nori.  That seaweed, [Wakame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakame), is Undaria pinnatifida, a completely different species with very different texture and use. It's usually used for soups and salads.  You'll have to ask the cashier how to turn that into nori, because there's certainly no information on doing so online.  I strongly suspect that this was a communication failure.

Even with the right seaweed, [making nori is a labor-intensive process](https://alicegordenker.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/how-is-nori-made/) that requires special equipment.  I'm also dubious that it would actually be cheaper than buying nori sheets.

What your brother-in-law can do, that might save some money and would certainly save storage space, is buy "raw" nori in 20-to-100-packs and [roast it on the stove himself](https://oureverydaylife.com/433894-how-to-toast-seaweed.html).  No oven required; nori is normally roasted over a burner on the stove.

Comment: I'll add that waving the regular nori around under the broiler works well too. Doesn't affect OP, but might be helpful to some.